# What does "to inform" mean, in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is the 2018 - 2019 goal of Natural Resources Canada written on the site:

> Canadians have access to cutting-edge research ***to*** **inform** decisions
>   on the management of natural resources.

I can't understand what 'to inform' means. Therefore, please paraphrase it or let me understand its meaning.

Comment: 'Inform' in this (sub-)sense is labelled, as far as I can see, 'obsolete' in the dictionaries listing it. It means 'that is useful/vital in making well thought-out [decisions]'.  'Influence' is close but not spot on.

Answer (score 1):

**To inform a decision** means to influence a decision ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inform)).

So, the sentence means the following:

> Canadians have access to cutting-edge research (which they can use in order to) to influence decisions on the management of natural resources.

The cutting-edge research which Canadians have access to will help them make better decisions on the management of natural resources.